# Fetching Comments using Youtube data API

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Im trying to fetch all the comments for a particular Youtube video.
I've written the following code:

```
#storing all the comments in a list (l)
def video_comments(url):
    # empty list for storing reply
    replies = []
  
    # creating youtube resource object
    youtube = build('youtube', 'v3',
                    developerKey=api_key)

    # retrieve youtube video results
    video_response=youtube.commentThreads().list(
    part='snippet,replies',
    videoId=url
    ).execute()

    for item in video_response['items']:
        
        # Extracting comments
        comment = item['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textDisplay']
          
        # counting number of reply of comment
        replycount = item['snippet']['totalReplyCount']

        # if reply is there
        if replycount>0:
            
            # iterate through all reply
            for reply in item['replies']['comments']:
                
                # Extract reply
                reply = reply['snippet']['textDisplay']
                  
                # Store reply is list
                replies.append(reply)
        comment = remove_URL(comment)
     
        # print comment with list of reply
        l.append(comment)
        for resp in replies:
            resp = remove_URL(resp)
            # print comment with list of replyprint(resp, replies, end = '\n\n')
            l.append(comment)
            
        # empty reply list
        replies = []

video_comments(n)
```

However, the following code fetches only 20-25 comments even though that video has hundreds-thousands of comments.

Answer (score 0):

The response has a **`nextPageToken`** attribute with its value - [see the documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#properties), then, you have to use that token - in order to get the next results.

Try this [example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Creplies%2Csnippet%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A10%2C%22videoId%22%3A%22pf3kMUZvyE8%22%7D):

```
https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=id%2Creplies%2Csnippet&maxResults=10&videoId=pf3kMUZvyE8&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

Response: Note in the response the `nextPageToken` attribute.

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#commentThreadListResponse",
  "etag": "priyTHCuTXn9LlRkKazYailhGq0",
  "nextPageToken": "QURTSl9pMlgzMi1IR0ZfTEtXZzNFRjQ1N3dEVmJlNXlPZ3BqUDFrMHlUejdxc3NIZFBOS013dWFRVjU5TWotWFJBaFJfUE1BSHR4aE9BQQ==",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 9,
    "resultsPerPage": 10
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
      "etag": "MezAPCqHnXHD4xfxGWCKw8GwMrk",
      "id": "Ugybh70lAXjKtWKnhVt4AaABAg",
      "snippet": {
        "videoId": "pf3kMUZvyE8",
        "topLevelComment": {
          "kind": "youtube#comment",
          "etag": "MfJ5ylnOGfVyfNlVM7qc0mSwLJQ",
          "id": "Ugybh70lAXjKtWKnhVt4AaABAg",
          "snippet": {
            "videoId": "pf3kMUZvyE8",
            "textDisplay": "Electricity is raw energy",
            "textOriginal": "Electricity is raw energy",
            "authorDisplayName": "Kevinzhw Zhang wang",
            "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AKedOLSU9_Tg183EZXdMmQbFcYKBw4WBajjPZc4gpT1W=s48-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
            "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCBCwvesq011-2OP1mXq6t8w",
            "authorChannelId": {
              "value": "UCBCwvesq011-2OP1mXq6t8w"
            },
            "canRate": true,
            "viewerRating": "none",
            "likeCount": 0,
            "publishedAt": "2021-12-24T05:59:47Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-12-24T05:59:47Z"
          }
        },
        "canReply": true,
        "totalReplyCount": 0,
        "isPublic": true
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
      "etag": "fiwm5vdcDBQh_CtyzB05jqp3h68",
      "id": "UgzoTdopkSulNGL_6tZ4AaABAg",
      "snippet": {
        "videoId": "pf3kMUZvyE8",
        "topLevelComment": {
          "kind": "youtube#comment",
          "etag": "pCGjZzOYwkp7Z4bbhF_DiutwSow",
          "id": "UgzoTdopkSulNGL_6tZ4AaABAg",
          "snippet": {
            "videoId": "pf3kMUZvyE8",
            "textDisplay": "Yo no tengo autismo y si intenté eso XD",
            "textOriginal": "Yo no tengo autismo y si intenté eso XD",
            "authorDisplayName": "XXX DDD",
            "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AKedOLTiD1hjwHmK8TWDil3XujkWfIFMvrc-_y0cTg=s48-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
            "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCXarJ5GGpaBLaV1KEPimQXA",
            "authorChannelId": {
              "value": "UCXarJ5GGpaBLaV1KEPimQXA"
            },
            "canRate": true,
            "viewerRating": "none",
            "likeCount": 0,
            "publishedAt": "2021-12-24T00:45:31Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-12-24T00:45:31Z"
          }
        },
        "canReply": true,
        "totalReplyCount": 0,
        "isPublic": true
      }
    },
    [other comments here...]
  ]
}
```